# Passing additional inputs to ParDo

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

What are my options for passing in additional inputs to ParDo transforms. In my case , I need to pass in about 5000 string objects to my ParDo. From what I understand, these are my options :

a) Pass it as side-input : But I suppose , that passing such as a huge sideinput might deteriorate the performance of my pipeline

b) Pass it as a parameter to the constructor of my ParDo class, and keep it as a class member : Could someone please tell me, that internally, how is this different from passing it as a side input ?

Are there any other ways to pass in additional inputs to a ParDo ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use case?

Answer (score 0):

Using a side input sounds like the best solution to your problem.  Side inputs are different from directly including the data in your DoFn because they can be read from external data sources at runtime.  Dataflow has roughly a 10MB limit on pipeline size, so if the data is larger than that you won't be able to include it directly in your DoFn.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear on the difference between passing it to constructor vs passing as a side input. But if you are passing it as side input, make sure you are setting `--workerCacheMb=<XXX>` appropriately. Having side input cached input in the memory makes element fetching faster.

For more details refer this documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/par-do#side-inputs